# How to solve the undefined symbol error in the built .so file?

Tags: linux, g++

I want to build a .so file in Ubuntu16.04. The version of gcc is:

```sh
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)
```

I have **student_info.cpp**, **student_info.h** and **Makefile** in the same dir.
The content of **student_info.h** is:

```c
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class student_info
{
public:
    student_info();

private:
    char* name;
    int score;

public:
    void setName(char* name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }

    void setScore(int score)
    {
        this->score = score;
    }

    char* getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    int getScore()
    {
        return this->score;
    }

};
```

The **student_info.cpp** is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "student_info.h"

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    student_info* student_info_new() {return new student_info();}
}
```

And the **Makefile** is:

```
student_info.so: student_info.cpp student_info.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC -o student_info.so student_info.cpp
```

After excute the `make` command. I get the **student_info.so**. But after using `ldd -r student_info.so`, I get the error below:

```sh
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff269fa000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2111228000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2111012000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2110c48000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f211093f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f21117ac000)
undefined symbol: _ZN12student_infoC1Ev (./student_info.so)
```

How can I solve this undefined symbol error? Thanks.

Comment: `echo '_ZN12student_infoC1Ev' | c++filt` shows `student_info::student_info()`. You need to provide a body for `student_info()` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ldd` says the default constructor of `student_info` is undefined. You need to provide a definition of the default constructor either in `student_info.h` or `student_info.cpp`. E.g.:

```
class student_info
{
public:
    student_info() : name(), score() {} // Declaration and definition.

private:
    char* name;
    int score;
// ...
};
```

Comment: It is really a simple question, LOL. Thank you anyway!